# Stackdriver policy does not resolved automatically

Tags: alert, policy, stackdriver

i've added new alert policy on stackdriver in our project to be notified when GKE upgrade is in progress.
i saw there are log entries that indicate such upgrade operation so i've created a log based metric (counter) for this long entries and created an alert then will fire the soon as this metric is above a Treshold of 0.
(Configured with 'any time series violates' with condition is above treshold of 0 for most recent value).

when upgrade started i do get an alert that it started as expected.
the thing is , when the upgrade is finished and this metric reach back to 0 , there is no 'resolved' operation on this policy.

why? what am i missing?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

As it mentions in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/incidents-events#open_incidents):

> If an incident (upgrade in this case) is open, then the policy's set of conditions is
> currently being met or there is no data to indicate that the condition
> is no longer met.

Regardless of that, the issue will be marked as 'resolved' when [no data is received for 7 days](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/incidents-events#closed_incidents) (after the upgrade is completed).